# Retain query string on rewrite .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have a simple rewrite that redirects

```
/photos/2
```

to

```
/photoviewer.php?photo=2
```

However I need to be able to allow the user to add a photo to their cart so I was thinking I need to retain the query string so that the following works.

```
/photos/2?action=purchase
```

redirects to:

```
/photoviewer.php?photo=2&action=purcahse
```

My current htaccess rule is:

```
RewriteRule ^photos/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ photoviewer.php?photo=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Append the `[QSA]` flag (query string append).

```
RewriteRule ^photos/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ photoviewer.php?photo=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesomely quick response! I will accept when the timer lets me.

Answer (score 2):

In your rule, replace `[L]` with `[L,QSA]`.
That will then retain the query information.

Hope this helps!

Comment: where L means Last, i.e. if the rule is matched, don't look at other rules.

Answer (score 1):

`[QSA,L]` instead of just `[L]` should do the trick. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

How about just extending the idea to pass "any" name/value pairs thru the URL to the photoviewer.php script? This is an elegant approach I've used in the past.

```
RewriteRule  ^photos\/([^/\.\-]+)\/([^/\.\-]+)$    /photoviewer\.php\?$1=$2    [L]
RewriteRule  ^photos\/([^/\.\-]+)\/([^/\.\-]+)\/([^/\.\-]+)\/([^/\.\-]+)$    /photoviewer\.php\?$1=$2&$3=$4    [L]
RewriteRule  ^photos\/([^/\.\-]+)\/([^/\.\-]+)\/([^/\.\-]+)\/([^/\.\-]+)\/([^/\.\-]+)\/([^/\.\-]+)$    /photoviewer\.php\?$1=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6    [L]
```

So, something like:

```
photos/photo/2/action/purchase
```

rewrites to:

```
photoviewer.php?photo=2&action=purchase
```