# .htaccess help issues passing GET variables on mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

Im a little puzzled here, i currently have the following rewrite rule to parse my pages...

```
 RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1
```

My problem is that this works great for what i need however if i want to add GET variables for extra areas then this doesn't work so say i have http://domain.com/page will direct to the page but using http://domain.com/page?do=this returns the page but does not pass the get variables?

I have tried using & because it parsing index.php?page=$1 but this just returns url not found?

Any help, pointers or advice would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retain query string on rewrite .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081641/retain-query-string-on-rewrite-htaccess)

Comment: You need the `[QSA]` flag to pass through the rest of the query string.

Comment: I searched and never found that post, perfect answer thanks so much Michael really appreciate your help :)